# Is there a way to encode HE-AAC(AAC LC SBR) streams using GStreamer with the audiotestsrc?

Tags: gstreamer, aac

Any help will be appreciated.
Is there a way to encode HE-AAC(AAC LC SBR) streams using GStreamer with the audiotestsrc?
This is what I've tried, but I could only encode the audio to a general AAC LC stream, and I don't know if there are any available options in the gst aac encoders.

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! capsfilter caps="audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)6" ! audioconvert ! fdkaacenc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mka
```

Answer (score 0):

While your audio source could be anything, the AAC encoding element `fdkaacenc` as of this writing does not support AAC object types other than LC at the moment.